# div hover not apply color CSS

Tags: html, css, hover

I'm missing something which is probably obvious here.

I'm attempting to change the font color to `#fff` (white) however it is not working. My background is applying, however, the `color: #fff;` is not applying to my font text and font icons. This use of `!important` also does not work.

**HTML:**

```
<!-- Categories  -->
    <div class="row categ">
       <!-- ACCOUNTING/FINANCE -->
        <a href="#">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3 categ-area text-center">
            <span class="icon-accounting"></span>
            <h3>ACCOUNTING/FINANCE</h3>
        </div>
        </a>
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
    a .categ-area:hover{
    background-color: #58ba2b;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Screenshot Example:
[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/dqt89276/1/

Comment: can you add a working fiddle?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dqt89276/1/

Comment: I'm managed to change the hover state of the `<h3>` but still having problems with the custom font icon hover state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a hover state to a child element too.

```
a .categ-area:hover, a .categ-area:hover span{
    background-color: #58ba2b;
    color: #fff;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dqt89276/3/

EDIT: added jsfiddle

Comment: Worked like a charm!! Thank you!

Comment: Huge pleasure :). This was new to me too so thank you for the question xD